# Maintain state between Controller calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this XML:

```
<Preferences>
    <Section Name="PREF_SECTION_NAME_1">
    <Preference Name="PREF_NOTIFY_1" Type="radio">    
            <Options>    
                <Option Name="PREF_OPT_YES" Value="true"/>    
                <Option Name="PREF_OPT_NO" Value="false"/>    
            </Options>    
            <Default>true</Default>    
        </Preference>
    </Section>
</Preferences>
```

I serialize this to a Model and pass to my View:

*part of my View*

```
case "radio":
    <b>@Html.Label(Model.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name)</b>

    for (var r = 0; r != Model.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options.Count(); r++)
    {
        if (Model.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Default == Model.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].Value)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name, Model.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].Value, new { @checked = true })
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name, Model.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].Value)
        }
    }
```

I (as the user) selects the 2nd radio button (false).

I then call my Controller method on the submit button and I get these values:

[image]

I need 'Default' to reflect the Users choice which in this case should be 'false'.

I have tried every combination I can think of but it is still always 'null'.

Sorry, I missed a bit of code out:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name, "Default")
```

The HTML Rendered:

```
<h1><label for="PREF_SECTION_NAME_1">PREF_SECTION_NAME_1</label></h1>
<div class="clear"></div>
<input length="4" id="Section_0__PreferenceModel_0__Type" name="Section[0].PreferenceModel[0].Type" type="hidden" value="radio">
<input length="4" id="Section_0__PreferenceModel_0__Name" name="Section[0].PreferenceModel[0].Name" type="hidden" value="PREF_NOTIFY_1">                            
<b><label for="PREF_NOTIFY_1">PREF_NOTIFY_1</label></b>

<input checked="True" id="Section_0__PreferenceModel_0__Name" name="Section[0].PreferenceModel[0].Name" type="radio" value="true">
<input id="Section_0__PreferenceModel_0__Name" name="Section[0].PreferenceModel[0].Name" type="radio" value="false">
<input length="7" id="Section_0__PreferenceModel_0__Name" name="Section[0].PreferenceModel[0].Name" type="hidden" value="PREF_NOTIFY_1">
```

My model:

```
[XmlRoot("Preferences")]
public class PreferencesModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Message to display to user on UI
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string MessageToUser { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Stores Preferences
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Section")]
    public List<Section> Section { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of Section (for Grouping Purposes)
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// List of Preferences for this section
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("Preference")]
    public List<PreferenceModel> PreferenceModel { get; set; }
}

public class PreferenceModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Type of HTML Control ie radio button, textbox
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of Preference
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    //[XmlAttribute("Default")]
    [XmlElement("DefaultValue")]
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool CheckBoxValue
    {
        get
        {
            bool flag;
            if (Boolean.TryParse(DefaultValue, out flag))
            {
                return flag;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            DefaultValue = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
     /// 
     /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("Options")]
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Option")]
public class Option
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: have you put the html.hiddenfor expression inside the form?

Comment: @StianStandahl yes. Of course. thanks

Comment: do you have a sample of the resulting html ?

Comment: @StianStandahl give me 1 minute :)

Comment: Not clear what your wanting to actually bind to here. Your radio buttons are binding to property `Name` but you have included a hidden input for that property previously so your radio buttons are ignored by the `DefaultModelBinder` (which is probably a good thing other wise the value of `Name` would be either `true` or `false`

Comment: My best guess is that you want to bind the radio buttons to `Default`. In any case, remove your `if` block - never set the `checked` attribute when using `RadioButtonFor()`. And the fact you generating inputs with `length="7"` means you have other errors as well (but you have not shown  the razor code for those)

Comment: @StephenMuecke hi, thanks for commenting.  I have tried previously not using hidden fields for this. .. beat me to it :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, not sure why I am getting lengths of 7. it is not set by me. Al I can think of is the bootstrap vedrion these guys r using here are setting this somewhere. Will try what u just suggested

Comment: Yes it is set by you :) (show the razor code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke just looking at this. what shoudl is use instead of the llop?

Comment: do you have a copy of the model?

Comment: Sorry, you have shown it. Count how many characters in the word "Default" :) - `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have shown u the razor code.there are only divs.  everything is shown as is. The company uses http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/ and this must be affecting these attributes because it is not definately not set by me

Comment: @StephenMuecke I see where u coming from now. But why is this an issue?

Comment: 1st thing 1st though. How do I show the the radio buttons - 2 off bound to the serialize object of the above xml?

Comment: The second parameter of `Html.HiddenFor()` is the `htmlAttributes` which is typeof `object` - you have used just a `string`. A `string` has only one property named `Length` and in your case there are 7 characters so it generated `length="7"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke +1 for the edcuation :)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you have a property `bool Default` and your wanting to display 2 radio buttons and if you select the first one - "PREF_OPT_YES" - that you want the value of `Default` to be set to `true` (otherwise `false`)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson do you have the code for the model ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke spot on - I have recently converted to MVC and would normally use json to send data back to server bit they do not want me using api controller so i am a fish out of water !

Comment: @StianStandahl yes.  Sorry.  Been busy reply to Stephen. will post edit nowish

Comment: OK, Need to finish something but I'll add an answer in 30-45 min

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you so much!

Comment: @AndrewSimpson can you also add the razor for the whole view? trying to replicate your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your radio buttons are binding to property `Name`, but you need to be binding to property `Default`. As it is, the values of the radio buttons are ignored by the `DefaultModelBinder` because you also have a hidden input bound to property `Name` (the `DefaultModelBinder` set only the first and ignores subsequent form values with the same name).

You also have a few other errors in the code including generating `length="##"` attributes in your html caused by adding a `string` value as the second parameter of `@Html.HiddenFor()` which is for adding `HtmlAttributes`, and setting the `checked` attribute (which you should never because its the value of the property your binding to which determines what is selected).

You code should be

```
case "radio":
    <b>@Model.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name</b>
    for (var r = 0; r != Model.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options.Count; r++)
    {
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Default, Model.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].Value, new { id = "" })
            <span>@Model.Section[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].Name</span>
        </label>
    }
}
```

A few things to note. Your use of `@Html.Label()` is not appropriate - You do not have an associated form control for property `Name`. Wrap the radio buttons in `<label>` elements and include the associated text so clicking on the text toggles the button. Remove the `id` attribute from

Comment: Thanks you make this look so easy. I had thought that @Html.Label() did not need an associated form control but @Html.LabelFor() did..?

Comment: Both generate a `<label>` element which is an accessibility element - clicking on it sets focus to its associated form control. If you have a `[Display]` attribute associated with the property, then you can use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.someProperty)` to output it.